# Why does my LM393N (dual comparator) ignore its inputs completely when used with an LED?

Tags: led, resistors, microchip, comparator

I have made the following circuit:

Viusalisation (not working):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDA85.png

Circuit (working):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fER6x4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Left to right, the pins on the chip are: vcc out2 in-2 in+2 and ground at the bottom

It always powers the LED with 3.3 V no matter what the inputs are, so the LED is always on. The circuit simply doesn't change, no matter which line or none at all are plugged into the inputs.

It is powered by the 3.3 V and 5 V connections of a Raspberry Pi. The resistor is 10K, but I've tried it with 1K and 100R as well and the circuit still doesn't work.

Comment: where is the input!?

Comment: If you're not plugging anything into the inputs, they're probably floating. Floating inputs == random noise == random outputs == bad.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, showing your work and findings in detail with a schematic. The schematic editor is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Max. Input voltage is limited at vcc + 0.3V. You should not apply 5V to a input when vcc is only 3.3V and expect the device to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but should it not a least work if in+2 is set to 3.3V and nothing is plugged in at in-2?

Comment: @Tonym I explained in the post what I tried already. Not sure how much further I could have gone with such a simple circuit

Comment: No, you should not leave any inputs floating. Connect vcc to 5V, apply 3.3V to the positive input and connect the negative input to ground. The led should be off. Reverse the inputs and the led should be on.

Comment: Could you draw your circuit using the built in circuit designer?   Schematic diagrams make it **much** easier to discuss circuits.  The LM393 is so well known I expect half the people here know the pin assignnents for it by heart, but it is still better to use schematics instead of wiring diagrams.  It also helps make clear to **you** what your circuit is supposed to be doing.

Comment: OP, see @JRE 's spot-on comment and look at other questions as a guide. You'll see how short your post is. Refer to my previous comment for reasons.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: To turn off when in-2 > in+2, which I does now, even though it doesnt seam to be very accurate